# Stick footer to bottom of wrapper, and get page to fit the whole space between nav & footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

Here is the problem,

I'm using bootstrap, and I face this problem :

I have a webpage, containing a wrapper divided in 3 distinct items.
First item is a bootstrap nav.
Second item is a div (class col-lg-12 -> bootstrap).
Third item is a div (class col-lg-12 -> bootstrap).

The navbar is always on top of the page, perfect.

Problem is that the footer must always be at the bottom of the page, I thought about absolute positionning but that doesnt fit, wrapper has some style attributes that footer should respect. AND, #page element has to fit the whole space (in height) between nav & footer. I mean that, even if there is only 1 text line in the #page element, the #page height must fit all available space.

ALSO CONSIDER THAT the #page div can contain MANY data, and so, its height can be bigger than the window height (at that moment, wrapper still contains all since it has a min-height 100% attr, and footer should still be under the #page element...)

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <nav></nav> <!--bootstrap item-->
        <div id="page" class="col-lg-12"></div> <!--bootstrap class-->
        <div id="footer" class="col-lg-12"></div> <!--bootstrap class-->
    </div>
</body>
```

Style, actually, looks like this :

```
<style>
    body,html{
        height:100%;
    }
    #wrapper{
        min-height:100%;
        border:2px solid red;
    }
    #page{
        border:2px solid blue;
    }
    #footer{
        border:2px solid green;
        position:relative;
        bottom:0;
        margin-top:20px;
        margin-bottom:15px;
        height:120px;
    }
</style>
```

I think the problem comes from the mix of custom css and bootstrap classes... but can't find any solution that fixes it... already went through many asked questions here on stack, but not working...

here is the actual fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/0eepqj4m/18/

thanks!

[image]

Comment: sorry i'll edit the image, i'm wrong with last one... *fixed

Comment: How does this look to you? http://jsfiddle.net/3ncdvuks/  Using flexbox

Comment: Are you willing to consider absolute positioning? I think it might work for your needs.

Comment: the main problem is to make #page fit whole space even if its contents are only 1 word (so just 5px height needed but HAS TO take all free height between nav & footer, see 2nd picture on my picture.... AND has to stop 20px before footer even if its contents needs much more height...) idk if i'm clear enough... I'd rather not use absolute, but if it can help solve my problem, why not...

Comment: The Bootstrap documentation has an example of a sticky footer. Any reason you're not just working from that?

Comment: the footer, now, is no more the problem. Absolute bottom + padding-bottom on the wrapper is ok for that. Now the problem is to fix middle div height to : all available space even when empty... http://jsfiddle.net/0eepqj4m/70/ :  the "blue box" should take all space, and stop 20px over the footer... even if the blue box is empty... and, if not, then all is ok since there is the padding on the wrapper... -> not solved yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're willing to use absolute positioning this would be easier.

Just add this to your footer:

```
position: absolute;
```

And then fix up a few on the other styles. Like adding `position: relative;` to the wrapper div, this gives the footer a reference to base it's position off of.

**EDIT**

Here's a jsfiddle with a short body length: 
http://jsfiddle.net/NateW/0eepqj4m/93/

Here's a jsfiddle with a long body length: 
http://jsfiddle.net/NateW/0eepqj4m/94/

**Another Edit**

If you want to use jQuery use something like this...
http://jsfiddle.net/NateW/0eepqj4m/92/

I modified the answer from this SO question: [set div height using jquery (stretch div height)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541115/set-div-height-using-jquery-stretch-div-height)

Comment: the question specifies none absolute.

Comment: @Persijn I think you have to deal with absolute position for this case.

Comment: yeh, but absolute does not fit. When my #page is gonna be higher than window height, it's gonna be a mess with footer... #page must take all space between nav & footer, and stop 20px over footer (margin top footer = 20px) http://jsfiddle.net/0eepqj4m/31/

Comment: @Julo0sS just add a padding-bottom to your #wrapper element (value : footer height + wrapper padding + your 20px margin)

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679601/how-to-make-bootstrap-sticky-footer-content-go-full-page-height

Comment: @Julo0sS check out my edited jsfiddle... does this achieve what you need?

Comment: @Julo0sS because your padding-bottom = your footer height, add wrapper padding + your 20px

Comment: @NateW In your example, you do not adapt #page height to its contents. you just set it to 1000px. That's false. If its contents need 2400px to display, then #page height will be 2400px, just under it there SHOULD be the 120px footer, and finally, wrapper finishes just under footer. Opposite, it #page contents needs 10px to display, then #page height will be ALL FREE SPACE HEIGHT between nav & footer on the window... get it?

Comment: @Freez no, http://jsfiddle.net/0eepqj4m/41/ : here, the BLUE BORDER must go to 20px over footer, even if #page contents is only "some text" ... adding your padding does not change anything

Comment: @Julo0sS You can remove the height from the content div and it will still expand properly. Check my updated fiddles for examples. Or am I still missing what you're saying??

Comment: @NateW in your fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/0eepqj4m/41/), check the blue border... it has to expand to 20px over the footer, in any case, with short content or long content...

Comment: @Julo0sS Ok, so you're saying that #page div needs to be 20px bigger(taller or wider?) than the #footer div?

Comment: @Julo0sS I see what you want but I'm not sure you can get out without javascript ...

Comment: @NateW lol, no... what i'm sayin is that : imagine, window is 1280px tall. Nav (we don't know its height but let's say that...) is 120px tall. Footer is 120px tall. SO in this case, considering that nav has a margin-bottom of 20px and footer has a margin top 20px, #page MUST be 1000px tall, and, even if there is only 1 word written into it... got it? :)

Comment: Ok, I think I get it! The #page div needs to expand to match the height of whatever the browser window is, in addition to expanding to match lots of content...

Comment: @NateW That's it! last update : http://jsfiddle.net/0eepqj4m/63/ (fixed footer to bottom & added padding-bottom to wrapper to be sure that #page does not get over it. But, #page is still smaller than what i wish

Comment: @Julo0sS - I don't know if you saw or not, but I added a jQuery example that replicates exactly(I hope!) what you're wanting... I don't know if jQuery is an option for you or not. Just thought I'd add it in case!

Comment: It is an option... but not the best... thought it would be easier than that to do the trick but seems like there is no real "easy" solution to that problem... JQuery does not fixes it each time since event is not always window.resize, most of the time, content is loaded through ajax call, so need to resize there, and, my "bootstrap" classes divs' contained in other div's make often the resize trick fail... anyway, thanks for help, mark your answer as accepted since it is the closest until now... Thanks

Comment: Yes, sometimes things aren't as easy as we'd like... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Getting the wrapper just right

[Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poi33/0eepqj4m/44/)

This is how i would solve it:
First remove this:
**css**

```
body,html{
    height:100%;
}
```

You don't want to limit your content to the size of the view port (html height 100%).

(this almost solves it)
Now it will work with most content except the small one since the entire wrapper will be to small.

for this we simply add:

```
#page {
    min-height: 50vh;
}
```

then it will keep taking up space even if its content is smaller :D

Comment: here is the last update... put some padding bottom to the wrapper & fix absolute footer works fine. BUT, my #page still does not fit all space... http://jsfiddle.net/0eepqj4m/63/

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using flexbox.  Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3ncdvuks/1/)

```
body,html{
height:100%;
}
.navbar {
  height:auto;
  flex-shrink:1;
}
#wrapper{
  border:2px solid red;
  min-height:100%;
  padding:2%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
 }
 #page{
  border:2px solid blue;
  flex-grow: 5;
}
#footer{
  margin-top:20px;
  position:relative;
  border:2px solid green;
  flex-grow:2;
}
```

Comment: #nav item should not adapt its size... #footer neither... flex-box does not solve anything...

Comment: @Julo0sS dont be so harsh. Its fully possible to add a bit for flex-basis to fix the sizing :P

Comment: @Julo0sS add a height:120px; and min-height:120px; to your footer and I think you have what you want